# We don't see a lot of each other

Tags: idiomatic-language

Consider the following sentences:

> 1. We don't see a lot of each other.
> 2. We don't see each other a lot.

Is there any difference in meaning between the two sentences?
Is the first sentence common?

Comment: @Man_From_India you're not wrong about the *literal* meaning of 'a lot of...', but this *is* idiomatic to native English speakers and means what the OP suspects it means.

Comment: @Astralbee This was really new for me. Well thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both mean the same thing - that you don't see each other *often*. However, note that example 1 is idiomatic in this context. "Seeing a lot of" something can also describe how much of something you have seen, not just how often. For example, if you said, "I don't see a lot of birds in my garden" that would mean that *numerically*, you don't see many. In the context of your example though, they would both be understood the same way by native speakers.